# Android Cache Manager

Tags: android, caching

I'm wanting to create my own cache manager for an Android app that I'm working on.  I know that the CacheManager exists and is for use with a WebView, however, it's listed as deprecated.  I thus need to be able to manage cache with my own implementation, but I haven't found anything that would help me do this.  Does anybody have any suggestions on where to start/how to do this?  I'm not finding a lot of information out there on how to create your own cache manager so I feel rather lost.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is not exactly answering your question, but take a look at this page that talks about using caching http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at this point in time it appears that there is no real way of managing the cache via webview.  I had to move on to using the httpURLConnection in order to attempt to manage cache.